# How to add tailwind elements to NextJs 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I want to add tailwind elements to my NextJs project but the documentation uses typescript and I use javascript and I have no idea of how to implement it. Is there any way to implement it to NextJs in javascript?

I tried the method given on the website but when I use the navbar component the expand button does not work. Like this, all components have some problems.

This is my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    "./node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily:{
      roboto:['Roboto']
    },
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
      boxShadow:{
        'nav':["[13px 25px 22px 5px #00000024,3px -4px 22px 31px #00000024]"]
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require("tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs")
  ],
}
```

This is my Navbar.jsx

```
const NavBarv2 = () => {

useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      const { NavBar, Input, initTE, Collapse, Dropdown } = await import("tw-elements");

      const myInput = new Input(document.getElementById("navbar"));

      const myNavBar = new NavBar(
        document.getElementById("navbar"),
      );
    }
    init();
  }, []);

  return(//Navbar from tailwind elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding tailwind to an existing project. You should start by installing the tailwind node module by using:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
```

Assuming you have a single repo setup, use these command in the root directory of your project(i.e. where the package.json file exists):

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

This will create a `tailwind.config.js` file at the root level in your project.

You could follow the rest of the instructions given in [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) for adding TW to an existing project.

Comment: I already installed tailwind css with nextjs. What should I do after that I tried everything in the documentation but it didn't work?

Comment: 1. Would you confirm that you have a `tailwind.config.js` file at the root level in your project?

2. Add the content of the file to the question.

3. Did you create a main css file and add tailwind directives to it?

BONUS: If possible, add the documentation and steps that you followed to your question, it helps the community to help you better. ;) (Without that, it is only a matter of time before this question will get flagged as low quality.)

Comment: Hey I have added my tailwind.config.js and the navbar file